# Static data member with initializer

Tags: c++, c++11

Assuming one is never odr-used, is there a benefit of declaring a `static const` or `static constexpr` data member with an initializer over declaring and then defining one later? Is there a benefit to not needing a definition?

Comment: some would argue it's easier to read if you define the variable where you declare it

Comment: @swang: You can't define a `static const` data member where you declare it. The declaration doesn't become a definition no matter what you do. However, the `constexpr` doesn't need a definition, and the `static const` with initializer doesn't need a definition if it's never ODR-used.

Comment: yes you can if it's of integral types

Comment: ok you are right you can declare it that way but it doesn't become a definition.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you can't define a `static const` data member where you declare it. The declaration doesn't become a definition no matter what you do (such as providing an initializer). However, a `static constexpr` data member doesn’t need a definition, and the `static const` data member of integral type with initializer doesn’t need a definition if it’s never ODR-used.

ODR: the *One Definition Rule*, in the C++11 standard §3.2 [basic.def.odr].

Providing a definition is non-trivial in a header file – for a non-template class the direct approach would lead fast to violations of the ODR, with the linker complaining. Thus a benefit of not defining is that it makes it easy to use header-only modules. And a benefit of defining is that it makes it easy to use any type whatsoever, and supports ODR-use.

There are already a host of SO questions dealing with practical solutions to the requirement of definition for ODR use, with respect to header-only modules.

The ODR has a special exemption for templates for this, and that’s the basis of one practical solution. Just provide the definition in a class template, and use a dummy argument to instantiate the template. Another practical solution is to place the definition in a function, essentially a Meyers’ singleton.